# Count distinct id where field exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create in ElasticSearch a query that will lists distinct `user_label.id` each with the respectiv counts:

Sample document looks likes this:

```
{
    "_index": "labels",
    "_type": "users",
    "_id": "484",
    "_version": 69,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "id": 484,
        "is_complete": 1,
        "language": "nl",
        "user_label": [
            {
                "guid": {
                    "163579": {
                        "order_id": 163579
                    }
                },
                "id": "boleto"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Mapping is type `nested`.

```
"user_label" : {
  "type" : "nested",
  "properties" : {
     "guid" : {},
     "id" : {
        "type" : "string"
     },
     "tag" : {
        "type" : "string"
     }
 }
}
```

I want to build a table like:

```
+---------------+-------+
| boleto        | 32453 |
| paid          | 34345 |
| reminder_sent |   345 |
+---------------+-------+
```

I have so far this for language, but need help creating for `user_label.id`:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "genders": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "language"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have tried using `"field":"user_label.id"` but it didn't worked. I tried this with type `properties` and for there the dot notation works, but doesn't seam to work with type `nested`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after some digging this is the outcome:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "user_label": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "user_label"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "id": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "user_label.id"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```